# assign a new value at a String array position in java

Tags: java, arrays, string

Please find my example code below:

```
    String[] tempCrfFC = crfFC;                //crfFC is a String[] itself
    for(int i = 0; i < crfFC.length; i++) {
        String[] crfTok = tempCrfFC[i].split("\\s");
        if(crfTok.length == 40) {
            if(crfTok[39].split("/")[0].equals("O")) {
                Double v = Double.parseDouble(crfTok[39].split("/")[1]);
                if (v <= d && (i == 0 || prevTagged != i-1)) {
                    tempCrfFC[i].split("\\s")[39] = "A";    //<-------
                    System.out.println("val: "+tempCrfFC[i].split("\\s")[39]);
                    System.out.println("tempCrfFC: "+tempCrfFC[i]);
                    prevTagged = i;
                }
             }
        }
    }
```

Example of a tempCrfFC line:

```
The  T       Th      The     null    e       he      The     null   Aaa     Aa    1       1       1       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       O       B       O       B       O       0       DT      O       O/0.892667
```

At the line marked with "<-----" I wish to reassign the existing value to a new value "A". However, on printing the output, the observation is that the value at that index (39) remains unchanged. Could someone help me resolve this?

Thank you.

Comment: What a mess... Sorry to say that, but I can't help it. First off: Clean up you variable names! A few extra characters won't bust your harddrive.

Comment: Share with me an example of cleaning up variable names.

Comment: I see a lot of unnececarly code. Just verify everything upto the "<-----" works yourself, and let us look at the "<-----" line only. You will need something like `tempCrfFC[i] = tempCrfFC[i].substring(0,38) + "A" + tempCrfFC[i].substring(40,tempCrfFC[i].length())`

Comment: For example: Expand `v` to `currentValue`. Rename `d` to whatever it actually stands for.

Comment: @rookie: `crfFC` and `crfTok` means nothing to anyone who isn't you. You aren't limited to 5 character, so make variable names meaningful.

Comment: I see. Will keep this in mind for the future. Thanks for the examples.

Comment: Why are you making `tempCrfFC` in the first place? This is just creating another reference to the same array. Changes to `tempCrfFC` will also effect `crfFC`.

Comment: @unholysampler: Yes, it is true. I now realize it's unnecessary. Will go ahead and remove it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
String[] tempCrfFC = crfFC;                //crfFC is a String[] itself
for(int i = 0; i < crfFC.length; i++) {
    String[] crfTok = tempCrfFC[i].split("\\s");
    if(crfTok.length == 40) {
        String[] parts = crfTok[39].split("/");
        if (parts[0].equals("O")) {
            Double v = Double.parseDouble(parts[1]);
            if (v <= d && (i == 0 || prevTagged != i-1)) {
                cfTok[39] = "A";    //<-------
                System.out.println("val: " + cfTok[39]);
                tempCrfFC[i] = join(cfTok);
                System.out.println("tempCrfFC: " + tempCrfFC[i]);
                prevTagged = i;
            }
         }
    }
}
```

where `join` is a method that joins your string back from an array.

Answer (score 2):

That's because your splitting is not being preserved:

```
tempCrfFC[i].split("\\s")[39] = "A";    //<-------
System.out.println("val: "+tempCrfFC[i].split("\\s")[39]);
```

If you look at that  `.split("\\s")` returns an array and `[39] = "A"` part sets the 39th element to "A". But, the generated array is gone. And then you do the splitting again and print the 39th element of the **new array** generated by second split.

Try something as follows:

```
String[] parts = tempCrfFC[i].split("\\s");    //<-------
parts[39] = "A";
System.out.println("val: " + parts[39]);
```

Answer (score 1):

tempCrfFC[i].split("\s") will give you a new string array. So your code should be like below

```
 String[] test = tempCrfFC[i].split("\\s");
 test[39]="A"; //Assuming test array has at least 40 elements
 System.out.println(test[39]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String[] tempCrfFC = crfFC;                //crfFC is a String[] itself
for(int i = 0; i < crfFC.length; i++) {
    String[] crfTok = tempCrfFC[i].split("\\s");
    if(crfTok.length == 40) {
        if(crfTok[39].split("/")[0].equals("O")) {
            Double v = Double.parseDouble(crfTok[39].split("/")[1]);
            if (v <= d && (i == 0 || prevTagged != i-1)) {
                crfTok[39] = "A";    //<-------
                System.out.println("val: "+crfTok[39]);
                System.out.println("tempCrfFC: "+crfTok);
                prevTagged = i;
                StringBuilder joined = new StringBuilder();

                // Save in original array:
                for (String s : crfTok) {
                    if (joined.length() != 0)
                        joined.append(' ');
                    joined.append(s);
                }
                tempCrfFC[i] = joined.toString();
            }
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are assigning the new value to a temporary array returned by the split() method and that new value is not replaced in the original string array,,

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the "A" to one of the `String` objects which are resulting from the `split(..)` operation. But you have to note that any operations on the split-result are not updated on the orginal object. So you have to update the orignal string too.

Replace the line

```
tempCrfFC[i].split("\\s")[39] = "A"; //<-------
```

by something like

```
String[] splitted = tempCrfFC[i].split("\\s");
splitted[39] = "A";
tempCrfFC[i] = "";
for (String s : splitted) {
  tempCrfFC[i] += s;
}
```

The part within the for-loop depends on your aim how to concat/join the string parts again.